# Comparing Float Column with another Float Column

Tags: python, pandas

let's say I have 2 columns, a and b.

```
 a      |      b
 1             2
 5             2
 4             3
 2             1
 2             1
```

I would like to compare 'a' and 'b' so that if the values in 'a' is more than value in 'b' then display those rows.

My desire outcome would be this:

```
 a      |      b
 5             2
 4             3
 2             1
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Where do you have these columns, are they already in a dataframe? Or are you reading a file?

Comment: `df[df.a > df.b]` ?

Comment: what about `df[df['a'] > df['b']]`?

Comment: already in a dataframe.

Comment: Thanks MaxU and Anton, both of your code works!